# How to import into a template excel file (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, templates, object

I have the code below to save data into a excel file(.csv).

```
private void SavedataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        now_status.Text = "save data to excel";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            selectedFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".csv";

            System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS");
            System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(selectedFileName, false, enc);
            int rowCountA = int.Parse(objA_n.Text);
            int rowCountB = int.Parse(objB_n.Text);

            string field;
            field = "Saved Data" + "\r\n" + "Numb,Time(S),AX,AY,BX,BY" + "\r\n";
            sr.Write(field);

            for (int i = 1; i < rowCountA + 1; i++)
            {
                string fieldA;
                fieldA = "A" + dn_objA[i].ToString() + "," + dtime_objA[i].ToString() + "," + dx_objA[i].ToString() + "," + dy_objA[i].ToString() + ",," + "\r\n";
                sr.Write(fieldA);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < rowCountB + 1; i++)
            {
                string fieldB;
                fieldB = "B" + dn_objB[i].ToString() + "," + dtime_objB[i].ToString() + ",,," + dx_objB[i].ToString() + "," + dy_objB[i].ToString() + "\r\n";
                sr.Write(fieldB);
            }

            sr.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }

    }
```

This Generates a simple excel file like this below. Object values will be inserted below the second row.
[image]

Is there a way to do the same thing, but into a template excel file? I have an excel file like the one below. 
[image]

I would like the imported data to show on the left hand side of the excel file.
Also, I want to use macros that I made in the second excel file shown.

Comment: Hi Atom. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do appropriate research before asking too broad questions. :) This place is more for specific issues you're having with code. And yes, there are ways of making C# interact with Excel. Either you can use the Interop (Microsoft.Office.Excel14) and open an Excel file from your program, or you can write an Addin. I use ExcelDNA to easily create addins for Excel.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was being specific.

Comment: You added a lot of detail, but your question boils down to: how do I make code that interacts with Excel? The top 3 google results will be a good start.